# List of all apps in SharePoint Online tenant

Tags: app, online, spo

I am trying to get a list of all apps installed across all site collections in my tenant. Not sure how to do it exactly as I am new to this. Any help would be appreciated. I have around 40K site collections in the tenant.

Answer (score 2):

Using the below PnP PowerShell command, we can get all apps from the tenant :

```
Get-PnPApp
```

This will return all available apps from the tenant app catalog. It will list the installed version in the current site.

Reference URL :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps

**Update:**

It seems in the new tenant or in the newly created site Get-PnPApp does not work - we may receive the below error:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot find resource for the request SP.RequestContext.curr
ent/web/sitecollectionappcatalog/."}}}
```

For this to get it fixed, contact to Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well this will work across that many sites, but managed to do this for my smaller organization. I found this article:  https://olafd.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/show-all-installed-apps-for-a-sharepoint-site/ helped me the most.

I started off running this against a few sites I knew had apps installed. I started by removing the condition block *if ($appType -eq "Instance")* - but I found that all the apps I was looking for were AppType : Instance, so I ended up adding it back in later

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
#Note: PnP Powershell v2.1.1 does not work with Powershell v5. Downgrade to 1.12.0 to use in PowerShell v5 (including ISE)
#Install-Module PnP.Powershell -RequiredVersion 1.12.0
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<domain>-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $Cred
$Url = "https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $Url –Credentials $Cred
$web = Get-PnPWeb –Includes AppTiles
$appTiles = $web.AppTiles
Invoke-PNPQuery
foreach ($appTile in $appTiles)
{
    Write-Host -f Green "Site:" $SiteUrl                  
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Title =" $appTile.Title
    Write-Host -f Magenta "AppType =" $appTile.AppType
    Write-Host -f Magenta "AppStatus =" $appTile.AppStatus
    Write-Host -f Magenta "AppSource =" $appTile.AppSource
    Write-Host -f Magenta "IsCorporateCatalogSite =" $appTile.IsCorporateCatalogSite
}
```

My final script to iterate across all sites is something like this:

----Note: replace the text *yourdomain* with the domain for your organization

```
#variables
$Cred = Get-Credential
$AdminURL = "https://yourdomain-admin.sharepoint.com/"  
$siteURLs = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/*"
$UserName = $Cred.UserName
$Password = $Cred.Password
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $Password

#Note: PnP.Powershell v2.1.1 does not work with Powershell v5. Downgrade to 1.12.0 to use PnP.Powershell in PowerShell v5 (including Powershell ISE)
#Remove-Module PnP.PowerShell -force
#Install-Module PnP.Powershell -RequiredVersion 1.12.0

    Try{
        #Import and connect to Sharepoint Online
        Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
        Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminURL -Credential $Cred

        #Get ALL Sharepoint sites
        $Sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

        #This script will jump down to the section labeled "Search all sites for 'real' sharepoint sites - not OneDrive etc"
        #This is because everything inbetween is a Function, and those Functions have not been called yet

        #Function to connect to the Sharepoint site
        Function ConnectToSPSite() {
            try {
                #Connecting to Sharepoint admin     
                Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminURL -Credentials $Credentials              
                try{
                    #Connecting to the Sharepoint site
                    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credentials                                                      
                } catch {
                            Write-Host "ERROR: Failed to connect to $($SiteUrl). Verify the user running this script has ownership rights on the site." -f Red
                            Continue
                    }
                
                #Call the Function GetAPPListItems to get installed Sharepoint applications.
                GetAPPItems                
            } catch {                
                Write-Host "ERROR: could not connect to Site:'$($SiteUrl)'" $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
                Continue               
            } 
        }

        #Function to get all apps from site
        Function GetAPPItems() {       
            Try{
                #Setup the connection to the Sharepoint site
                $SiteConn = ""
                $SiteConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $Credentials -ReturnConnection               
                $error.clear()

                #Get the site information including the site Apps
                try{
                    $web = Get-PnPWeb –Includes AppTiles
                    $appTiles = $web.AppTiles
                    Invoke-PnPQuery

                    #Review all apps
                    foreach ($appTile in $appTiles)
                    {   
                        #Filter out to show only the Apps that are the AppType: "Instance"
                        If($appTile.AppType -eq "Instance"){

                            #Write out this information for the user running the script
                            Write-Host -f Green "Site:" $SiteUrl                  
                            Write-Host -f Yellow "Title =" $appTile.Title
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "AppType =" $appTile.AppType
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "AppStatus =" $appTile.AppStatus
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "AppSource =" $appTile.AppSource
                            Write-Host -f Magenta "IsCorporateCatalogSite =" $appTile.IsCorporateCatalogSite
                        }
                    } 
                }catch{
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error running Get-PnPWeb on site" $SiteUrl
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error:" $errormsg
                    Continue
                }
            }catch{
                    Write-Host -f Red "Unable to connect to PnP site" $SiteUrl
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error:" $errormsg
                    Write-Log "Unable to connect to PnP site" $SiteUrl
                    Write-Log "Error:" $errormsg
                    Continue
            }
        }

        #Search all sites for 'real' Sharepoint sites - not OneDrive etc
        foreach($site in $sites)
            {
                #Empty variables that change often
                $SiteURL = ""
                $SiteConn = ""
                #Check the site URL to see if it is a 'real' SharePoint site. Omit empty sites.
                $SiteURL = $site.URL
                If ($site.URL -like $siteURLs -and $site.StorageQuota -ne 0)           
                    {                                        
                        #Call the Function ConnectToSPSite to begin by connecting to the SharePoint site
                        ConnectToSPSite             
                    }  
            }
    
    } Catch {
        Write-Host "ERROR: $errormsg"
    }
```